# Upscaling TIFF orthophoto using AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects

I have an orthophoto that loses resolution when you zoom in. Each pixel is 25cmx25cm.

I am aware of the advances that have been made lately in the world of photo editing using AIs.

I wonder if there is any way to improve the resolution of this orthophoto using AI.

I have tried several online tools as well as Adobe Lightroom, After Effects, Photosop, etc. with no remarkable results.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing which can truly upscale a low resolution raster image, and add real details that are not in the original. It's really not possible. Garbage in = garbage out. You can often resample images in Photoshop (or similar software) say 2 or 3 times, and get away with it, maybe apply some sharpening, but it's never going to look like a true high resolution image.

However with some AI software you can add details, but you have to remember that AI image enhancement essentially invents the detail, often by employing a database of sample images. So, what you get is not a real image. Adobe's software doesn't have anything like this except for the neural filters in Photoshop for portrait enhancement - but it only works with faces currently. Perhaps they will improve on it, given time.

A quick google and I found [Image Upscaler](https://imgupscaler.com/) - I have no affiliation with this site or its developers. You can use it for free for few images, but there are paid plans. There are several websites that offer something similar.

You really need to start with the non zoomed image (not a pixelated one). Something like this

[image]

Run it through the online upscaler

Here's the result. It's certainly not perfect, a few wonky cars, but not too bad either considering the level of enlargement. It has done a splendid job on the trees and bushes. It seems to be recognizing the cars as some kind of solid object (not necessarily as an actual car unfortunately). However it does kind of demonstrate the limitations of AI enhancement currently available. Who knows what the future might hold!

[image]click to see full size

Comment: Actually Photoshop's Neural Filters *does* have an image upscaler called *Super Zoom*. It's not only for faces. I've tried it on this image, but the result is pretty bad. It works very differently on different kinds of images.

Comment: @Wolff - yeah I know. That's my experience too, not so good THB, which is why I didn't mention it. Perhaps Adobe will improve it given time.

Comment: I am having similar results with other tools I tried. Seems that technology is not there yet.